# display message below the extjs grid

Tags: extjs, grid

I just want to add hint below the grid.

**E.g.** "Please select only coal type".

Any suggestions please. Tried with toolbar. It actually displays a text box.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting your question properly but i think you want to show text in toolbar

```
bbar: [
    { xtype: 'tbtext', html: 'Sample Text Item' }
]
```

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.toolbar.TextItem.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it may help you.

```
dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'tbtext',
            html: "Please select only coal type"
        }]
    }]
```

[Sample Fiddle Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ihn)